# recursive definition in CPP

Tags: c++

I meet a problem like this: **UPDATE**

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    int i;
    B b;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(){}
    int j;
    A a;
};
```

When I define it in one .h file, it would give an error. I think the problem is the recursive definition. But could someone help me how to solve such issue?

1. `error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'b'   c:\users\xingyo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cppalgo\recudef\test1.h   9   1   RecuDef`
2. `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\xingyo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cppalgo\recudef\test1.h   9   1   RecuDef`
3. `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\xingyo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cppalgo\recudef\test1.h   9   1   RecuDef`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? The example you give contains errors and leaves us guessing. Did you really mean to declare a nested class `class B` inside class `A`, etc.? That wouldn't be recursive. Also, if you get an error **tell us what that error is**. The first step to solving an error is to know the error.

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not possible verbatim in C++. The explanation is that the compiler needs full, not just forward, declaration of a class to be able to use it as a member of another class. It simply needs *the size* of a class object.

The workaround in C++ (and in C) is to use **a pointer** or **a reference** as a member of one of the classes. That way you can use forward declaration as follows:

```
class A; // forward declaration

class B {
    // ...
    A* pa;
};

class A { // full declaration
    // ...
    B b;
};
```

It's your (not the compiler or runtime) responsibility to keep the instance of `A` that instance of `B` points to (or references) valid.

Comment: Please be decent and say why you downvote.

Answer (score 6):

You can't solve it. It's meaningless. You've defined A to contain B which contains another A which contains another B which ... You can't possibly have intended that. Maybe you need to use a pointer or a reference?

Comment: Those are not instance declarations, there is no recursion going on here at all.

Comment: They weren't but the OP's edit makes it so.

Comment: It's not just meaningless, it's physically impossible. If what the OP wanted to would compile, it would create a data structure of infinite size. ;)

Comment: It's not just physically impossible, it is logically impossible. I.e. meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Split you codes into 4 files, say A.h, A.cpp, B.h, and B.cpp.

```
// A.h

class B;
class A {
public:
    A();
    B* b;
};

// A.cpp

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A() : b(new B) {
}

// B.h

class A;
class B {
public:
    B(A* a_);
    A* a;
};

// B.cpp

#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B(A* a_) : a(a_) {
}
```

And use them this way:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main() {
    A a;
    B b(&a);

    // do logics

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a recursive problem. Declare the classes without the definitions:

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
   ...
};

class B
{
   ...
};
```

See: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/034.htm

Comment: Forward declarations only work for pointers and references.

Comment: @Dima that's not correct. They also work for classes, structs, and namespaces, and probably unions as well.

Comment: @Dima: He will have to use a pointer or reference anyway, it is simply physically impossible to have two classes or structs contain each other, as the result would have infinite size.

Comment: @EJP, you can certainly forward declare classes, structs, and namespaces.  But you cannot declare an object of a class or struct that has only been forward declared, because its size is not yet known to the compiler.  You can only declare a pointer or a reference to a forward declared class or struct.

Comment: I agree. That's a bit different to 'forward declarations only work for pointers and references', isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a recursive definition like that in C++.  Before you can declare an object of `class A`, `A` must be fully defined, so that the `sizeof(A)` is known to the compiler.  Same with B.  However, you can get around it by using pointers.  You can declare a pointer to an object of `class A` by simply "promising" to define `class A` at some later point.  This is called *forward declaration*.

```
class B;  // forward declaration

class A
{
  B *b;
};

class B
{
  A *a;
};
```

Forward declarations also work for references.