# C++ incomplete type class

Tags: python-2.7, incomplete-type

i made a class in c++ and it had a member of the same class and it gave a incomplete type class error.

```
class A{
    private:
        A member;
};
```

i found these
["Incomplete type" in class which has a member of the same type of the class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349822/incomplete-type-in-class)
,[Incomplete Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276134/incomplete-type)
these gave a very good explanation as to why the error happened and how to fix it.

but for practice i made the same code on python 2.7 and it was able to make a class with a member of the same class.

my question is HOW(whats the explanation) python is able to do that, and possible difference between c++ and python on handling this particular problem

python code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,t):
        self.key=t
        self.lc=None
        self.rc=None

parent=node(10)
lc=node(5)
rc=node(15)
parent.lc=lc
parent.rc=rc
```

Comment: You can't put a class instance as a member into itself in c++. That would lead to infinite recursion. Also you're missing a semicolon after the class declaration.

Comment: yea i got that explanation for the c++, i wanted to know how and why python is able to do that

Comment: Well, it is a bit unclear if you ask about c++ or python.

Comment: @Nikhil would you show the python code that you want explanation for?

Comment: Python and C++ are not even remotely similar. Comparing them is entirely pointless. Please ask a meaningful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has duck typing and doesn't actually create the member object before your call to its constructor.

In Python your variable can even contain a string and then later a class object. I don't see how you would have 'the same code'. You don't specify the type of your variables and they can contain whatever you want, only raising errors when wrongly manipulated.

In C++ the member `A` will be created at the same time as the class, leading to an infinite recursion.

[Use a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300420/recursive-definition-in-cpp) if you want to choose when to allocate the member.

Comment: by same code i meant same as in using the class object as a member of class.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

```
>>> class A:
...     aa = A()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in A
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I get this in both Python 2.7 and 3.5.